# Shotwell imports videos into the wrong folder 1970/01/01

Tags: shotwell, photo-management

I'm using Shotwell 0.30.10. I've imported some videos and Shotwell copied them to the wrong place. Instead of putting them in the folder path for the correct date, it put them in `/library_path/1970/01/01`.

I could manually move them to the correct folder using the file manager, but then their location is not consistent with Shotwell's database. What is the right way to move files within the library?